# Integerring: Is there a smart and fast way to calculate the modulo of big numbers (of power > 128 ( basis 2)) stored as an array?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, integer-rings

Is there a smart and fast way to calculate the modulo of big numbers (of power > 128 ( basis 2)) stored as an array ? Are there some tricks, or theorems I could look up to ?

I thought about expressing that number as power  $a^b \mod\text{ big number}$  maybe creating the possibility to shorten the time complexity of the usual division modular algorithm. This power (powmod) can be fastly computed.
But I suspect that the logarithm in integerrings isn't that fast ;)

Comment: The discrete logarithm problem is indeed (believed to be) hard, but exponentiation can be done easily, if that's your question, see [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: Even the slow PARI/GP allows probable-prime tests for numbers with thousands of digits. Only if you insist in proven primes having no specific structure , it can be quite time consuming. In principal , PARI/GP can also do that.